# Use Data Extension multiple times in Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I'm dealing with a Salesforce data model (imported via imports, not data stream) and struggle with the contact builder setup for my event and decision checks. Basically it requires that I link a data extension multiple times because there are multiple paths from the contact to the extension.

1. Contact - Subscription - Product
   (the person who booked the product subscription)
2. Account - Subscription - Product
   (the company of the contact above)
3. Contact - Assignment - Subscription - Product
   (the person who uses the product subscription, can be the same as 1 but also some other contact of the same Account)

Naturally I would set up an attribute set for each path to follow and contact builder allows me to do so without a hitch. However, when I then come to the contact filter tab on events or decision splits I only see the data extension names once without knowing which path the filter assumes.

Does anyone know how to handle that without creating duplicates for every path I need, which wouldn't be very scalable.

Thanks in advance for your support!